# robot_state_publisher Catkin_make ERROR

Tags: ros, catkin-make, robot-state-publisher

I am using **Ubuntu 20.04** LTS desktop and ros **Noetic**

i have installed this library **robot_state_publisher** for integrate the imu and Lidar,

when I clone the repo from GitHub in my workspace *src* folder
then I came back to workspace and I did `catkin_make`

I want to use tf to get updated in real-time using this package

it gave me an **Error** :
the Error is following:

````
-- ~~  - rviz_imu_plugin
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
CMake Error at /opt/ros/noetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_workspace.cmake:100 (message):
  This workspace contains non-catkin packages in it, and catkin cannot build
  a non-homogeneous workspace without isolation.  Try the
  'catkin_make_isolated' command instead.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:69 (catkin_workspace)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/aiot/ros_slam/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/aiot/ros_slam/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Invoking "cmake" failed```
````

Answer (score 0):

Please build the package with **catkin_make_isolated** instead of **catkin_make**.

- **catkin_make** treats the entire workspace as a single cmake project,
  and builds it with a single invocation of cmake. Since catkin_make
  treats the entire workspace as a single package, it's faster for
  incremental builds that only change code, but slower when you need to
  regenerate the build files, and more sensitive to dependency issues
  between packages.
- **catkin_make_isolated** treats each package as a separate cmake project, and builds and installs each separately, in dependency order. This is why it's able to build plain cmake packages.

Comment: after runing ```catkin_make_isolated```
it gives me an error like 
```Error: Packages with unknown build types exist
Can not build workspace with packages of unknown build_type ```